# Insert Image Link from Google Drive into Google Sheets After Uploading an Image via Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-apps

To preface, I'm super new to programming in general, nevermind javascript.

I'm developing a web application where a user can upload a picture by clicking on a button.  This action will upload pictures into a certain directory in my google drive with a unique folder and name.

Now, I'm trying to copy and paste the google drive link of a picture any time it has been uploaded.

I am able to successfully get the ID of the picture URL in my getFileUrl() method.  But when I call that method within my doStuff1() function then later insert that info into userInfo.fileUrl, I am getting https://docs.google.com/document/d/undefined/ as the output in my spreadsheet.
How can call that value?

Updated: I am realizing that when I use "google.script.run.getFileUrl("fn","i"), that is when I'm getting "undefined".  When I run the getFileUrl() function locally, I do get the value that I want.  **Please advise how I can use .WithSuccessHandler(function) correctly so that I can return the value of "fileId0".**

---

This is the front end, where a user uploads the picture

**page.html**

```
  <html>
  <head> 
   <body>
   <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">
          <i class="material-icons right">insert_photo</i>
          <span>Import Picture</span>
          <input id="files" type="file" name="image">
        </div>

        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input disabled selected type="text" class="file-path 
             validate" placeholder="Choose an image">
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </form>

 <?!= include("page-js"); ?>

</div> <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER-->


 </body>
</html>
```

This is part of the javascript to put relevant info in an array, which will later be used to append a row in the google sheet

**page-js.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>    
 <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>


 <script>
document.getElementById("addAnother").addEventListener("click",doStuff1);



    var i=1;
    var num={};


    function doStuff1(){

       num.picNum2=i;
       var personName=document.getElementById("fn").value;

       var fileId00=google.script.run.getFileUrl("fn","i");

       var userInfo ={};

       userInfo.firstName= document.getElementById("fn").value;
       userInfo.number=i;
       userInfo.fileUrl="https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+fileId00 
       +"/";


       i++;

       google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);

    }
```

This is part of the javascript to upload picture file into the Google drive

**(still part of page-js.html)**

```
  var file, 
  reader = new FileReader();
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'- '+today.getDate();

  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    if (e.target.error != null) {
      showError("File " + file.name + " could not be read.");
      return;
    } else {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
   .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result,num.picNum,date,$('input#fn')
   .val(),$('input#date').val());

    }
  };

   function showSuccess(e) {
    if (e === "OK") { 
      $('#forminner').hide();
      $('#success').show();
    } else {
      showError(e);
    }
  }


     function submitForm() {


    var files = $('#files')[0].files;

    if (files.length === 0) {
      showError("Please select a image to upload");
      return;
    }

    file = files[0];

    if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
      showError("The file size should be < 5 MB.");
      return;
    }

    showMessage("Uploading file..");

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);


  }

        function showError(e) {
    $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
  }

  function showMessage(e) {
    $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
  }

 </script>
```

This part grabs the array "userInfo" and appends the content in a row within a designated google sheet.  Any time, I click on the button in the front end, it creates a new row.

**Code.gs**

```
  //google sheet web script

    var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXX";

   function getFileUrl(fn,i){

  try{
      var today0 = new Date();
       var date0 = today0.getFullYear()+'-'+(today0.getMonth()+1)+'-' 
       +today0.getDate();

      var dropbox0 = "OE Audit Pictures";
      var folder0,folders0 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox0);

     while (folders0.hasNext())
       var folder0=folders0.next();

      var dropbox20=[date0,fn].join(" ");


      var folder20,folders20=folder0.getFoldersByName(dropbox20);
      while (folders20.hasNext())
         var folder20=folders20.next();


         var file0, files0= folder20.getFilesByName(i);
      while (files0.hasNext())
        var file0=files0.next();


        var fileId0=file0.getUrl();


       return fileId0;
          }  catch(f){
  return f.toString();
        }
    }


  function userClicked(userInfo){

     var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
     var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
      ws.appendRow([userInfo.number,new Date(), 
         userInfo.firstName,userInfo.fileUrl]);

      }

   function include(filename){
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();  
    }


  function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, fn, date) {

    try {

    var dropbox = "OE Audit Pictures";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
      } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }


   var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
     bytes = 
       Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),

       blob=Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file)

       var dropbox2=[fn,date].join(" ");
       var folder2, folders2=folder.getFoldersByName(dropbox2)

       if (folders2.hasNext()){
           folder2=folders2.next().createFile(blob);
       } else {
          file = folder.createFolder([fn,date].join(" ")).createFile(blob);
        }
       return "OK";

       } catch (f) {
      return f.toString();
       }    
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In `doStuff1()` of "page-js.html", you want to give a value returned from `getFileUrl()` of "Code.gs" to `userInfo.fileUrl`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- `google.script.run.getFileUrl()` doesn't return values. When you want to use the values from `getFileUrl()`, you can use `withSuccessHandler()` as following modified script.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `doStuff1()` as follows.

```
function doStuff1() {
   num.picNum2 = i;
   var personName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(doStuff2).getFileUrl("fn","i"); // Modified
}

// Added
function doStuff2(fileId00) {
  var userInfo = {};
  userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
  userInfo.number = i;
  userInfo.fileUrl = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+fileId00 +"/";
  i++;
  google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, I used `doStuff2()` for retrieving the values from `getFileUrl()`. If you want to modify the function name, please modify it.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you! This returns a link!   Couple issues still: in the process of adding a new row with user entries (please see "Code.gs" -> ws.appendRow(...)), a link is added on a separate row from rest of the values in the array "userInfo".  Furthermore, I get this output instead of a link when I pass user-input "fn" and "i":  "TypeError: Cannot call method "getFilesByName" of undefined.".   This issue goes away and I get the correct output when I set fn and i as fixed values in the getFileUrl(fn,i) function (also manually created a folder with name "fn" and a file named "i" within).  Can u help?

Comment: the first issue- a link added on a separate row-- was a self-inflicted problem.  Please ignore

Comment: please find the new question in the link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670567/inserting-a-link-of-a-picture-that-had-been-added-to-google-drive-into-a-google

Comment: @Harry Lee Thank you for your response. I asked one question for your new question. Could you please confirm it?