# Inserting a Link of a Picture That Had been Added to Google Drive into a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

This is a second part to the problem that had been resolved here: [Insert Image Link from Google Drive into Google Sheets After Uploading an Image via Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653772/insert-image-link-from-google-drive-into-google-sheets-after-uploading-an-image)

I'm developing a web application where a user can upload a picture by clicking on a button. This action will upload pictures into a certain directory in my google drive with a unique folder and name.

Now, I'm trying to copy and paste the google drive link of a picture any time it has been uploaded.

With the help of @Tanaike, I was able to get the link of the url from google drive into the google sheet when I pre-assign a part of the folder name (fn) and the picture title (i) within the getFileUrl(fn,i) function in "Code.gs".  But I get this "TypeError: Cannot call method "getFilesByName" of undefined." output whenever I try to pass the user-input "fn" and "i".

---

**page.html**
--This is the front end, where a user uploads the picture

```html
  <html>
  <head> 
   <body>
   <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">
          <i class="material-icons right">insert_photo</i>
          <span>Import Picture</span>
          <input id="files" type="file" name="image">
        </div>

        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input disabled selected type="text" class="file-path 
             validate" placeholder="Choose an image">
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </form>

 <?!= include("page-js"); ?>

</div> <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER-->


 </body>
</html>
```

This is part of the javascript to put relevant info in an array, which will later be used to append a row in the google sheet

**page-js.html**

```js
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>    
     <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>

     document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("loadend",doStuff1);
      
   document.getElementById("addAnother").addEventListener("click",doStuff1);
     
     <script>
     
     function doStuff1(){
        
           num.picNum2=i;
           var personName=document.getElementById("fn").value;
           google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(doStuff2).getFileUrl("fn","i"); // Modified by Tanaike
   
            
           var userInfo ={};
           userInfo.firstName= document.getElementById("fn").value;
           userInfo.number=i;
          userInfo.fileUrl=fileId00;        
          num.picNum=i;
           i++;
     google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
       
        }
        
          // Added by Tanaike
          function doStuff2(fileId00) {
            var userInfo = {};
            userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
            userInfo.number = i;
            userInfo.fileUrl = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+fileId00 +"/";
            i++;
            google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
          }
</script>
```

This is part of the javascript to upload picture file into the Google drive

**(still part of page-js.html)**

```js
var file, 
  reader = new FileReader();
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'- '+today.getDate();

  reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    if (e.target.error != null) {
      showError("File " + file.name + " could not be read.");
      return;
    } else {
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
   .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result,num.picNum,date,$('input#fn')
   .val(),$('input#date').val());

    }
  };

   function showSuccess(e) {
    if (e === "OK") { 
      $('#forminner').hide();
      $('#success').show();
    } else {
      showError(e);
    }
  }


     function submitForm() {


    var files = $('#files')[0].files;

    if (files.length === 0) {
      showError("Please select a image to upload");
      return;
    }

    file = files[0];

    if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
      showError("The file size should be < 5 MB.");
      return;
    }

    showMessage("Uploading file..");

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);


  }

        function showError(e) {
    $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
  }

  function showMessage(e) {
    $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
  }

 </script>
```

This part grabs the array "userInfo" and appends the content in a row within a designated google sheet. Any time, I click on the button in the front end, it creates a new row.
This is where if I set fn and i values within the getFileUrl function manually and have a correponding picture and a folder under the designated directory, I get a valid link back in my google sheet.  However, if I leave the argument as variables that the user input in the web app, I get the aforementioned error in my link within the sheet.

**Code.gs**

```html
//google sheet web script

    var url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXX";

   function getFileUrl(fn,i){

  try{
      var today0 = new Date();
       var date0 = today0.getFullYear()+'-'+(today0.getMonth()+1)+'-' 
       +today0.getDate();

      var dropbox0 = "OE Audit Pictures";
      var folder0,folders0 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox0);

     while (folders0.hasNext())
       var folder0=folders0.next();

      var dropbox20=[date0,fn].join(" ");


      var folder20,folders20=folder0.getFoldersByName(dropbox20);
      while (folders20.hasNext())
         var folder20=folders20.next();


         var file0, files0= folder20.getFilesByName(i);
      while (files0.hasNext())
        var file0=files0.next();


        var fileId0=file0.getUrl();


       return fileId0;
          }  catch(f){
  return f.toString();
        }
    }


  function userClicked(userInfo){

     var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
     var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
      ws.appendRow([userInfo.number,new Date(), 
         userInfo.firstName,userInfo.fileUrl]);

      }

   function include(filename){
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();  
    }


  function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, fn, date) {

    try {

    var dropbox = "OE Audit Pictures";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
      } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }


   var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
     bytes = 
       Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),

       blob=Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file)

       var dropbox2=[fn,date].join(" ");
       var folder2, folders2=folder.getFoldersByName(dropbox2)

       if (folders2.hasNext()){
           folder2=folders2.next().createFile(blob);
       } else {
          file = folder.createFolder([fn,date].join(" ")).createFile(blob);
        }
       return "OK";

       } catch (f) {
      return f.toString();
       }    
     }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? About ``This is where if I set fn and i values within the getFileUrl function manually and have a correponding picture and a folder under the designated directory, I get a valid link back in my google sheet.``, can I ask you about the sample correct values of ``fn`` and ``i``?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood, but do you want the link of the file or the folder path? Because if it's only the link, the id of the file is enough: https://drive.google.com/file/d/yourfileId

Comment: @Jescanellas I'm trying to get the file link. so I've also tried setting the getUrl() up to return the fileId-- still getting the same error.

Comment: @Tanaike   Say if I make a folder named "2019-6-20 Joe" and insert a picture file named "1" inside of it.  If I set the function like this, then I will get a valid link back in google sheet->getFileUrl(fn,i) {var fn= "Joe"; var i="1"; (then the rest of the function) };

Comment: It's like when I run google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(doStuff2).getFileUrl("fn","i"); in my doStuff1() function, I'm unable to pass the "fn" and "i" info that the user has inputed

Comment: The problem is Drive is not a directory based system. When you run the script to upload the file to Google Drive, it returns you the id of the file, so that is enough to get the link as I said in my previous comment. Sorry if I'm not addressing correctly to the issue.

Comment: Oh I see.  can you please advise how I can do that in the context of my code?  What I've done previously is to replace var fileId0=file0.getUrl() to .getId() in "Code.gs", then make userInfo.fileUrl=" drive.google.com/file/d/"+fileId00+"/"

Comment: @Harry Lee Thank you for replying. I noticed that the discussions have already been progressed. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jescanellas and @Tanaike commented, the better approach is to fix your code editing the function doStuff2 in page-js.html as this:

```
function doStuff2(fileId00) {
            var userInfo = {};
            userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;
            userInfo.number = i;
            userInfo.fileUrl = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+fileId00 +"/";
            i++;
            google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
          }
```

About the error you're getting, you're not using the brackets in the whiles, this is causing the errors because only takes the first line after the while inside the loop. **Code.gs**:

```
while (folders0.hasNext()) {
     var folder0=folders0.next();

     var dropbox20=[date0,fn].join(" ");


     var folder20,folders20=folder0.getFoldersByName(dropbox20);
     while (folders20.hasNext()) {
         var folder20=folders20.next();


         var file0, files0= folder20.getFilesByName(i);
        while (files0.hasNext()) {
        var file0=files0.next();


        var fileId0=file0.getUrl();


       return fileId0;
       }
   }
}
```

Regarding your question about the file Id, you can get it easily after you create the file, because this will return you a File object from which you can get the ID using the getId method [1]:

```
file = folder.createFolder([fn,date].join(" ")).createFile(blob);
fileId = file.getId();
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file

Comment: Hi Andres.  I have set the function the way mentioned and getting an error code as follows:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/TypeError: Cannot call method "getFilesByName" of undefined./

Comment: I'm curious.... is there any way I can grab the file ID when I'm uploading the file into the drive (so the function uploadFileToGoogleDrive in Code.gs) then return the id back to doStuff2?